# How Can I Get Elementary To Open First Using A Dual Boot With Windoz 10?

Tags: boot, dual-boot

How can I get Elementary OS to open first when turning on the computer using a dual boot with Windoz 10?

Yesterday I used a USB Live version of Elementary and loaded it into the computer.
The computer is an Acer Aspire One laptop. It is about two years old. I used Rufus to create the USB drive. It selected the Elementary OS from a different external hard drive. Not the internal HDD. The sha256 was verified to be correct.

To boot the USB drive with Elementary the laptop was started and F2 was pressed. That didn't work. The USB wasn't listed. Only two Windoz names were in the list. I used the BIOS to switch the order of those two Windoz items. When the machine was restarted all that was displayed were large white letters on a black screen. I didn't know what that was so I restarted and switched them back to the way they were.

I restarted and pressed F12. That gave me the choice of the thumb drive with Elementary. Elementary was selected and Enter was pressed. Elementary opened and the try Elementary was seen with a countdown. The trackpad didn't work during this time. No cursor was seen. The OS opened and it was tried.

Then the install Elementary button was selected and the process was begun.

The choice to dual boot was selected. When the time to resize the partitions for Windoz and Elementary came, the bar was slid to have 68 GB for Windoz and 930 GB for Elementary. The process was continued until it finished.

When the computer was restarted Windoz opened. I don't want that. I want Elementary to open.

The machine was restarted and F2 was pressed. When I got to the BIOS Elementary wasn't listed. Just those two Windoz lines were there. I let Windoz open during one of my many restarts and decided to look at the drive space. I allocated 68 GB for Windoz and the partition was only 13 GB. That is waaaay different than 68 GB. That is a problem that needs to be fixed.

So here are the problems that I want to fix. I want Elementary to open when I press the power button. I don't want to need to press F12 every time the computer is turned on to get to Elementary. How do I do that? Let me say this, when pressing F12 the computer password is required. After it is entered the choices of Windoz and Elementary are seen; but there is no way to swap them on this screen. The only thing that is allowed is to select the drive. Pressing F6 in this window will not switch their order.

Secondarily how do I fix the drive allocation to be what I want it to be? I want Windoz to have 68 GB storage. Not 13 GB. I understood that Windoz might need some other space for swap or backup, but taking up 55 GB seems crazy. How do I enlarge that Windoz partition to be as big as I want it to be?

Here is what I will be doing. I will be reformatting the entire drive and putting Windoz 10 back on the drive and starting from the beginning. I need instructions to tell me how to load Elementary from the USB drive so that when I turn on the computer by pressing the power button Elementary will open first. I can press F12 to get to Windoz 10 when needed. Maybe I made a mistake using Rufus and that is the source of the problem. I don't know.

Secondly how should I move that slider to allow Windoz some space so that it actually has at least 60 GB usable drive space and not end up with just 13 GB or such a ridiculous number?

If you feel that I can accomplish this without having to start over please instruct me how to do it.

I used Elementary from 2012-2014 and liked it. It opened and closed much faster than Vista and Ubuntu. I tried it again in 2018 but it was very slow to open and close. It wasn't as fast as before. So I didn't keep it. I chose Ubuntu Budgie. Budgie got buggy in the last few months. Now I'm trying Elementary again. I hope it works out this time. It is a little faster than before but not as snappy as in 2014.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I see it is really time to make a tutorial for beginners. However I will try to explain. I recommend to make a backup of data to dropbox, mega.nz or one drive, Google drive of files from Windows which are important. Then install Windows from the scratch. After Windows installation, check the drive size in Windows disk manager. Look for in Google how to use this tool. Then just make some empty space for Elementary there by resizing the disk in Windows, but just leave as empty space, do not make partition. Then prepare bootable usb stick with Elementary OS iso file using balena etcher or rufus.

Comment: Disable fast boot in Windows 10 in power management. Reboot. Press F12. Choose usb stick. Start Elementary OS installer. When it will ask to install the Elementary OS alongside, just select with mouse the empty space and Elementary OS will know what to do and it will install there. I mean it will create the partitions there on empty space itself. Wait till the end of the installation process which is long. When it will say that it finished follow exactly step by step what installer will say at the end, to avoid issue with the GRUB installation. Ar the end you should just remove usb stick and G

Comment: And just end the installation process. It should reboot and menu should show with Windows 10 and Elementary OS in the list.